# General Solution of Second Order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I saw that I can transform any general second order ODE $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$ to an ODE of the form $y''+f(x)y'+y=0$ or $y''+g(x)y=0$.

Can I find a general solution to equations from these kind?
( Just like first order ODEs have general solution).

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know. One general method available is the power series method in the case that $f$ an $g$ are analytic. For many choices of $f$ and $g$, the solutions are known as *especial functions*. For instance, the solutions of $y''-x\,y=0$ are the [Airy functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function).